# Unable to disable or delete any plugin in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android-studio

I want to disable or uninstall some plugins installed in Android Studio on my Mac computer:

[image]

Here you have the Preferences-> Plugin screen:

[image]

As you may see, there is no way to disable or delete any installed plugin.

What can I do to get the option to disable or delete any plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

(On the second photo you provided)

head to the "installed section" and right click on any installed plugin and press "uninstall"